# How to add metadata to a Modern Page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, metadata, sitepages, modern-pages

In your Site Pages library let's say you have a Wiki Page and a Site Page (i.e. modern page).

When I add a choice column, let's call it Category, I see the field show in the edit form for the Wiki Page and can select a value and Save.

However, the field does not show for the Site Page. This tells me **metadata cannot be added to modern pages**.

Does anyone know if this is the case?

Any way meta data can be added for a modern page?

Purpose is to build out our information architecture and facilitate better search with refiners, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This doesnt seem to be possible yet via the UI.

However, based on this [Customize "modern" site pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link, I was able to add metadata using CSOM C#. You can also modify the same code for PowerShell.

You need to ensure that you have the latest CSOM dll installed or atleast one after March 2017.

So I have a choice column whose internal name is `TestChoiceCol` and the options are `Oreo,Good-day and Parle-G`. Its available for Wiki Page and Web Part page content types but not for Site Page as seen in below screen grab.

[image]

The code is modified from the above link only.

The code is as below:

```
Web web = context.Site.RootWeb;
List pagesLibrary = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");

ListItem item = pagesLibrary.RootFolder.Files.AddTemplateFile("/sites/start/SitePages/mymodernpage1.aspx", TemplateFileType.ClientSidePage).ListItemAllFields;

// Make this page a "modern" page
item["ContentTypeId"] = "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118";
item["Title"] = "My Modern Page1";
item["ClientSideApplicationId"] = "b6917cb1-93a0-4b97-a84d-7cf49975d4ec";
item["PageLayoutType"] = "Article";
item["PromotedState"] = "0";
item["CanvasContent1"] = "<div></div>";
item["BannerImageUrl"] = "/_layouts/15/images/sitepagethumbnail.png";

//custom choice column named TestChoiceCol, replace it to Category for your case
//add your other custom columns here
item["TestChoiceCol"] = "Oreo";

item.Update();
context.Load(item);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Above code runs successfully but the custom column wont show up on the edit properties page of the modern pages.

So, I ensured that the library is crawled and mapped the property to a `RefinableStringxx` property as below:

[image]

Waited for couple of minutes and then it got the data i wanted on a custom search page.

[image]

So, yes currently its possible to add metadata but only via CSOM C# or PowerShell code and not via UI.

Also, please upvote on this User voice link - [Enable custom columns for modern page](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/31437259-enable-custom-columns-for-modern-pages)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a huge shame. I can't ask my content editors to run a script every time we want to tag a page, which is essentially every time a new page is created. They're not technical and the user journey is horrible. But if Microsoft haven't implemented metadata for modern pages via the GUI yet I guess there isn't another option.

Comment: MS surely didnt think this through. Should have been documented somewhere atleast. Also, fully agree with you. We can't ask content editors to run the script everytime, this needs a better story.

Comment: Gautam, please see a workaround I have found. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I tried this at my end. It works fine at first, but when i try to edit the page afterwards, its giving me unexpected error. Check this -  [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgMyY.png). If its one time thing, then go with it, else its bound to cause problems in "unexpected" ways.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but could not. For clarity, I applied all the steps below, then I checked the file in. Checked it back out, changed the value of the column, Saved, then checked back in again. No error. Were your steps different?

Comment: I edited the modern page after changing the content type and tried to add webpart. It threw this error.

Comment: Ah, yes now I get the same error. As you say, this workaround would only be practical if you didn't need to make further changes to the page.

Comment: Precisely, if its a one time thing, go for it. But if the editors want to change the content/add webpart etc afterwards they will face this error. After viewing this error, i was not able to add webparts on the page either.

Comment: Also, if you are not very keen on "modern" pages, you can deactivate them. Just go the Site Settings > Manage Site features (web scoped) and deactivate the Site Pages feature. See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIMIQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

So I found a workaround that can be applied via the GUI that seems to work for me:

### Process

1. Create a column, e.g. a Choice column, in the Site Pages library
2. Create a new Site Page (i.e. modern page) in the Site Pages library
3. Edit the properties of the newly created page
4. Change the Content Type from Site Page to Wiki Page

[image]

5. The page will refresh and you will see the newly created column

[image]

6. Choose a value for the column and click Save. The page now has this
   value assigned.

[image]

### Observations

- Interestingly, despite changing the content type from Site Page to
  Wiki Page, when the page is clicked/accessed it still loads as a
  modern page
- Once the content type is changed to Wiki Page, the page can no longer be edited without seeing an error message
- You cannot seem to change the content type back to Site Page
- Not a great user journey for content editors, but at least it's
  doable via the GUI

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully added columns to the new communication site template, site pages library. I just added a choice column. I made News one of the categories (and set it as default) as any items published from the landing page will sit in this library as well. I tried to create separate document libraries, add the site pages content type to separate the content. The main Site pages library will eventually have hundreds of news articles in as well and I didn't want that to all be in one library. However - when I create a page in the "new" library - it automatically moves it back to the original site pages library. So strange. Anyway - category column works fine.